# jquery chenge function not working on dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

jquery change function on dropdown is not working at my application and working at [jfFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uMqD4/)  
Application code

```
<select id="title" name="title"><option value="">-select-</option>
  <option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss.</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#title").change(function () {
        var value = $("#title").val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Why?

Is there anything i am doing wrong???

Comment: Do you get any errors ? are you sure the HTML in your fiddle matches the HTML in your browser on output ?

Comment: Please add the generated markup instead of your asp.net code.

Comment: yup i am sure coz the markup i used at fiddle is just a copy paste of html generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a class for your dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.title, 
    new[] { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr", Value = "Mr" }, 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs", Value = "Mrs" }, 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" }, 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other" } 
    }, 
    "-select-",
    new { @class = "myddl" }
)
```

and then perform a class selector instead of an id selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myddl').change(function () {
        // use $(this) to get the currently changed dropdown list here
        // instead of performing yet another selector
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

I suspect that you have multiple dropdown lists with the same `id` (in a `<table>` or something) which is invalid HTML.

Comment: it works, but question is still there i.e why jquery selector not selecting element by its id (as i can see at dom there is only one element with id "title" )?

Comment: @djCool, I would be very surprised if an id selector in jQuery didn't work if you really had a single DOM element with `id="title"`. That would really be catastrophic for the jQuery project I think. How did you verify that you have a single DOM element with id="title"? Are you using AJAX? Are you adding elements dynamically to your page?